# complex join query

Tags: php, mysql, mysql5

I have MYSQL tables as follows

```
user TABLE {id INT}

profile TABLE {user_id INT, facebook_id varchar(50)}

messages TABLE {id INT, message TEXT, from_id INT, type enum('main','facebook'}

messages_to TABLE {user_id varchar(50), message_id INT}

profile.user_id REFERS To user.id
- the messages_to.message_id refers to the messages.ID column.
- the messages_to.user_id refers to profile.user_id IF messages.type = 'main' BUT
  if message_type = 'facebook' THEN messages_to.user_id REFERS to profile.facebook_id
```

I want to do a join query that basically selects all the messages to a specific person, but the thing is the messages_to.user_id can refer to either `the person's facebook ID or the person's ID (a reference to user.id column).`

So basically the query should work as follows

- it should select all the messages in messages table, and if `messages.type = 'facebook'` checks if messages_to.user_id equals the person's FACEBOOK ID. (note that messages_to table stores the recipients for each messages ID)
- BUT if the `messages.type = 'main'` checks if the `messages_to.user_id` equals the `person's USER ID (USER.id)`

Is it possible to do a `mysql join query` for that efficiently?

messages_tos table stores ALL the recipients for each message in the MESSAGES table. THERE CAN be MORE THAN ONE RECIPIENT for a message.

Comment: are you sure you need separate table to store facebook_id ? How about have in User table a field facebook_id, which can be either null or has a value. Whenever someone creates account via facebook, you create User on fly with some random username (or use facebook's e-mail) and random password. Then you can always use user_id and if you have facebook user, you first checks corresponding user_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is the query.

```
SELECT messages.*,profile.* 
FROM messages 
JOIN messages_to ON messages.id = messages_to.message_id
JOIN profile ON 
  (profile.user_id = messages_to.user_id AND messages.type = 'main') 
  OR (profile.facebook_id = messages_to.user_id AND messages.type = 'facebook')
```

Answer (score 1):

something like that?

```
select m.*, u.*
from messages m
inner join messages_to mt
on m.id = mt.message_id
left join profile p
on    ( m.type = 'facebook' and mt.user_id = p.facebook_id)
   or ( m.type = 'main' and mt.user_id = p.user_id)
left join users u
on p.user_id = u.id
```

why do you have your `messages` and `messages_to` tables split up and do not use a single table for this? (i'm assuming an 1:1 relation)

Comment: I think it's to make messages have 1 or more recipients.

Comment: ace: hm, makes sense :) but then i would rename the table to `recipients`